# Bring back removed code

Tags: git

I did some deletions some time ago in a git repository and I'd like to bring some of them back, maybe bits of code, or entire files. Which is the most elegant way of doing this?

Can I do some kind of interactive diff between my actual state of the file and the old state of the file and just copy/paste stuff from the old version?

Comment: git does keep deleted code(commits) for a few days(don't know exactly the exact number though) so try checking the git's garbage collector maybe.

Comment: @hus787: git keeps every commit, including those that delete code. It's always possible to go back to any previous commit.

Comment: @Arjan no, no, you misconstrued what I tried to say. I meant commits which are not part of any branch. `git checkout some_commit` -> make changes -> `git commit` -> `git checkout master`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `git checkout` with a path:

```
git checkout fa1afe1 -- some/file.txt
```

This will overwrite `some/file.txt` with how it looked in commit `fa1afe1`, without switching `HEAD`. You can then add it with `git add` or selected parts of it with `git add -i`, as usual, and commit.

There is also `git checkout -p` to overwrite only selected parts in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

use `gitk path/filename` to show that file's history only. External diff is simple way to see old versions for copy/paste.  Also you can pick commit id and use it for `git revert`.

Or just gitk and use the filter, like 'touching path' to hilight and navigate. At any commit point you can see the tree instead of patch.

And really there are just too many ways...

Answer (score 0):

Provided you have made a commit before you can checkout to it using the commit id.

```
git checkout commitId
```